# Flex Spark Form Horizontal layout

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I have a Spark form with horizontal layout and I would like to reduce the top and bottom vertical padding.
Neighter using the `paddingBottom`/`paddingTop`  on the `HorizontalLayout` nor using the `paragraphSpaceAfter`/`paragraphSpaceBefore` of the `FormItem` reduces the vertical space before and after the form.

```
<s:Form width="100%" height="50%" fontSize="15">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout  verticalAlign="middle"  gap="3" paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0">
        </s:HorizontalLayout>
    </s:layout>
    <s:FormItem   > 
        <mx:DateField id="selDateFrom" formatString="DD/MM/YYYY" selectedDate="{new Date()}">
        </mx:DateField>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem > 
        <mx:DateField id="selDateTo" formatString="DD/MM/YYYY" >
        </mx:DateField>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

Can someone help me?

Davide

Comment: You will have to create your own s:FormSkin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a custom `FormSkin` like this one and it works:

```
  <s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" 
        alpha.disabled="0.5">
    [...]
    <s:Group id="contentGroup" showErrorSkin="true" showErrorTip="true" 
             left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:layout>
            <s:FormLayout gap="7"/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:Group>
  </s:Skin>
```

Thanks